# move files, depending on their first letter - powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 1 disk, on my home server, which has all my media in, and where my films download to. I wonder if you could suggest a quick way to move files, to different hard drives, on the letter they start with. E.g my H drive has all my media, I would like files beginning with A-F to drive D, files G-L to drive F and files M-Z to drive E. So far I have  ‘Move-Item H:\done\C* D:\ -Force’ line for every letter of the alphabet. Just wondered if there was a quicker was of moving the files.

A work colleague provided me with a script, but it doesn't work, and not sure if its me doing something wrong or the script:

```
#get a list of files at the source
$files = gci H:\done


#loop through each item in the variable "$files" which will then on be referenced to using the variable "$file"
foreach($file in $files){

#assign the drive letter using a switch statement. Switch statements are a quick way to return a new value based on if a condition is met... in this case if the first letter of the input matches the regex statement.
  $drive =  switch -regex ($file.basename[0]) {

       '[A-F]' {'D:\'}
       '[G-L]' {'F:\'}
       '[M-Z]' {'E:\'}

   }

#quick way to show progress
   write-host "Moving $($file.Name) to $drive" -f Cyan

#perform the move
   Move-Item $file.FullName $drive -Force -Verbose


}
```

Comment: Take advantage of poweshell's helpful `[char]` type.

Comment: `$var = @(65..90); for($i=0;$i -lt $test.length;$i++){
[char]$test[$i] = $test[$i];
}`

Comment: Can you elaborate about _"but it doesn't work"_ ? Do you get error messages? Do you have permission to move files to the root of these drives? BTW if you do not use switch `-File` on the Get-ChildItem cmdlet, it will return both FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$files = dir C:\Users\Neko\Desktop #Whatever directory
$var1 = @(65..70); 
$var2 = @(71..76);
$var3 = @(77..90);
echo work3
for($i=0;$i -lt $var1.length;$i++){ [char]$var1[$i] = $var1[$i]; }
for($i=0;$i -lt $var2.length;$i++){ [char]$var2[$i] = $var2[$i]; }
for($i=0;$i -lt $var3.length;$i++){ [char]$var3[$i] = $var3[$i]; }
foreach($file in $files){
    if($file.name[0] -in $var1){$drive = 'D:\'}
    if($file.name[0] -in $var2){$drive = 'F:\'}
    if($file.name[0] -in $var3){$drive = 'E:\'}
    write-host "Moving $($file.Name) to $drive" -f Cyan
    MI -path "$file.fullname" -destination $drive -Force
}
```

This is very basic powershell coding. I was able to sort the files into `$var1`, `$var2`, and `$var3` categories since they listed ascii characters for the letters you wanted and then converted them to letters using the for loops, a bit convoluted but this is the easiest way to do this in my opinion. You then loop through the `$files` variable where it takes everything from the directory you in the variable, in my case `C:Users\Neko\Desktop\*` and for you it would be `H:\done\*` and seperates them into categories from the `$var1` `$var2` `$var3` we mentioned earlier and sets the `$drive` variable. It then moves the files.

**ERRORS WITH YOUR COLLEAGUE'S CODE**

- `[A-F]` does is not the same as a number group like `(1..100)` and would not do anything except produce errors.
- `$file.basename` isn't necessary compared to just the normal `$file.name` if you are only going to take the first character. Its just typing extra letters.

Overall, it was good, but not enough to accomplish your task. Full code for your case:

```
$files = dir H:\done
$var1 = @(65..70); 
$var2 = @(71..76);
$var3 = @(77..90);
echo work3
for($i=0;$i -lt $var1.length;$i++){ [char]$var1[$i] = $var1[$i]; }
for($i=0;$i -lt $var2.length;$i++){ [char]$var2[$i] = $var2[$i]; }
for($i=0;$i -lt $var3.length;$i++){ [char]$var3[$i] = $var3[$i]; }
foreach($file in $files){
    if($file.name[0] -in $var1){$drive = 'D:\'}
    if($file.name[0] -in $var2){$drive = 'F:\'}
    if($file.name[0] -in $var3){$drive = 'E:\'}
    write-host "Moving $($file.Name) to $drive" -f Cyan
    MI -path "$file.fullname" -destination $drive -Force
}
```

Comment: Hey Neko, Thank you for this. One question, do i leave the var value as (65..70) etc or put the letters i require?

Comment: The numbers are the ascii equivalent of the letters, you would have to leave the var vaues as is

Comment: Ascii codes `65-70` are `a-f` and `71-76` is `g-l` and `77-90` is `m-z`

Comment: UPDATE: As of PS 6 I found out you can use the rang operator with letters using `('a'..'f')` but I have powershell ver 5.1.18362.752 so I did not realize this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators?view=powershell-7#range-operator- If you have any success with that method or my previous method, mark it as answered and if it doesn't work, let me know.